# How do I calculate this limit using power series?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion, power-series

I have to calculate the following limit using power series, but I'm really bad at it and don't even know how to start. Could someone please explain in detail? also what's the difference between a power series and a Taylor expansion?

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{e^{z^2}-1}{(e^z-1)^2}$$

Comment: Every Taylor polynomial is a power series. Hint for this question: can you approximate $e^x$ for very, very small $x$ up to first order?

Comment: Multiply and divide with $z^2.$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. By `{e^z}^2`, which is $e^{2z}$, did you mean `e^{z^2}` ($e^{z^2}$)?

Comment: yes, im sorry i did mean $e^{z^2}$

Answer (score 2):

First we observe that we can expand $e^z$ in a power series:
$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ which implies that  $e^z-1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ and $e^{z^2}-1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2n}}{n!}.$ Now we can compute the limit

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{e^{z^2}-1}{(e^z-1)^2}=\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2n}}{n!}}{(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!})^2}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z^2(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n}}{n!})}{z^2(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!})^2}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1+(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2n}}{n!})}{1+(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!})^2}=1$$

Might be easier to see if you don't look with the "sum" notation and open the sum instead.